# where to find the list of function of nodes in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to find what the meaning of `nodes.transform` as well as other functions it has.

Truly, it's very hard to find the documents for chef even google can't rescue me.

Can anyone point me to the document for that? or any useful resources?

Comment: It does not look like node's method, in fact it's more like some array's method, which does not have anything to do with Chef. Show us more code.

Comment: Seems yes, it's not chef. I'm still too beginner for ruby. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for each of the Chef releases can be found on http://rubydoc.info. Here is the documentation for the latest Chef release: http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/11.4.4/frames

Comment: Thank you! I just known I can find it in rubydoc. This is really helpful.